# Is it possible to profile Tensorflow with Tensorboard in Azure Databricks?

Tags: azure, tensorflow, azure-databricks

I have a Tensorflow model in an Azure Databricks notebook and I have setup Tensorboad to visualise metrics from it. I would also like to be able to profile training but if I try to capture a profile from localhost:6009 it fails. Is it possible to do this in Azure Databricks?

Comment: Did you follow this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/applications/deep-learning/single-node-training/tensorflow#--tensorboard

Comment: Yes, I followed the linked article. My Tensorboard logs scalars, histograms etc. properly but doesn't allow me to profile.